# python: run a process with timeout and capture stdout, stderr and exit status

Tags: python, process, external-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [subprocess with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

What is the easiest way to do the following in Python:

- Run an external process
- Capture stdout in a string, stderr, and exit status
- Set a timeout.

I would like something like this:

```
import proc

try:
    status, stdout, stderr = proc.run(["ls", "-l"], timeout=10)
except proc.Timeout:
    print "failed"
```

Comment: Just so we know where you're starting from, have you considered the `subprocess` module? http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: no - looks like that is a big leap forwards

Comment: subprocess' Popen.communicate with timeout, similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout

Comment: @Mark: good catch, marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hate doing the work by myself. Just copy this into your proc.py module.

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys

class Timeout(Exception):
    pass

def run(command, timeout=10):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    poll_seconds = .250
    deadline = time.time()+timeout
    while time.time() < deadline and proc.poll() == None:
        time.sleep(poll_seconds)

    if proc.poll() == None:
        if float(sys.version[:3]) >= 2.6:
            proc.terminate()
        raise Timeout()

    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    return stdout, stderr, proc.returncode

if __name__=="__main__":
    print run(["ls", "-l"])
    print run(["find", "/"], timeout=3) #should timeout
```

Comment: This version might timeout due to pipe buffer overflow (when stdout or stderr ~64K).

Comment: If the command times out, you won't get any output generated up to the timeout.

Comment: print run(["ping www.redicecn.com"], timeout=10),the script threw out Timeout exception, but the ping process was still running.

Answer (score 12):

Note on linux with coreutils >= 7.0 you can prepend timeout to the command like:

```
timeout 1 sleep 1000
```