# Linux Shell Script: How to detect NFS Mount-point (or the Server) is dead?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nfs, nfsclient

Generally on NFS Client, how to detect the **Mounted-Point is no more available or DEAD from Server-end**, by using the Bash Shell Script?

Normally i do:

```
if ls '/var/data' 2>&1 | grep 'Stale file handle';
then
   echo "failing";
else
   echo "ok";
fi
```

But the problem is, when especially the NFS Server is totally dead or stopped, even the, `ls` command, into that directory, at Client-side is hanged or died. Means, the script above is no more usable.

Is there any way to detect this again please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"stat" command is a somewhat cleaner way:

```
statresult=`stat /my/mountpoint 2>&1 | grep -i "stale"`
if [ "${statresult}" != "" ]; then
  #result not empty: mountpoint is stale; remove it
  umount -f /my/mountpoint
fi
```

Additionally, you can use rpcinfo to detect whether the remote nfs share is available:

```
rpcinfo -t remote.system.net nfs > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo Remote NFS share available.
fi
```

Added 2013-07-15T14:31:18-05:00:

I looked into this further as I am also working on a script that needs to recognize stale mountpoints.  Inspired by [one of the replies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7179628/134536) to "Is there a good way to detect a stale NFS mount", I think the following may be the most reliable way to check for staleness of a specific mountpoint in bash:

```
read -t1 < <(stat -t "/my/mountpoint")
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
   echo NFS mount stale. Removing... 
   umount -f -l /my/mountpoint
fi
```

"read -t1" construct reliably times out the subshell if stat command hangs for some reason.

Added 2013-07-17T12:03:23-05:00:

Although `read -t1 < <(stat -t "/my/mountpoint")` works, there doesn't seem to be a way to mute its error output when the mountpoint is stale. Adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` either within the subshell, or in the end of the command line breaks it. Using a simple test: `if [ -d /path/to/mountpoint ] ; then ... fi` also works, and may preferable in scripts. After much testing it is what I ended up using.

Added 2013-07-19T13:51:27-05:00:

A reply to my question "[How can I use read timeouts with stat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751556/how-can-i-use-read-timeouts-with-stat)" provided additional detail about muting the output of stat (or rpcinfo) when the target is not available and the command hangs for a few minutes before it would time out on its own. While `[ -d /some/mountpoint ]` can be used to detect a stale mountpoint, there is no similar alternative for rpcinfo, and hence use of `read -t1` redirection is the best option. The output from the subshell can be muted with **2>&-**. Here is an example from [CodeMonkey's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751753/134536):

```
mountpoint="/my/mountpoint"
read -t1 < <(stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-)
if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; then
  echo "NFS mount stale. Removing..."
  umount -f -l "$mountpoint"
fi
```

Perhaps now this question is fully answered :).

Comment: I utilized the stale NFS mount point detection in my script **nfs_automount**, [now available on GitHub](https://github.com/vwal/nfs_automount).

Comment: Nice answer.  I have seen `read -t1 < <(stat -t "$MOUNT_DIR" 2>&-)` provide a return value of `142`.  So doing `[ ! $? -eq 0 ]` as a test is probably better.

Comment: Another point: `read -t1 < <(stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-)` will leave an open file handle (or similar) to the mounted folder.  Hence the mount option will fail if you don't use the `-l` flag.  You can use `timeout 1 stat -t "$mountpoint" > /dev/null` instead.  This will kill that `stat` command and hence kill it's open file handle.

Answer (score 3):

The final answers give by Ville and CodeMonkey are almost correct.  I'm not sure how no one noticed this, but a $REPLY string **having content is a success**, not a failure.  Thus, an **empty** $REPLY string means the mount is stale.  Thus, the conditional should use -z, not -n:

```
mountpoint="/my/mountpoint"
read -t1 < <(stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-)
if [ -z "$REPLY" ] ; then
  echo "NFS mount stale. Removing..."
  umount -f -l "$mountpoint"
fi
```

I have ran this multiple times with a valid and invalid mount point and it works.  The -n check gave me reverse results, echoing the mount was stale when it was absolutely valid.

Also, the double bracket isn't necessary for a simple string check.

Answer (score 1):

Building off the answers here, I found some issues in testing that would output bad data due to how the $REPLY var would get updated (or not, if the result was empty), and the inconsistency of the stat command as provided in the answers.

This uses the stat command to check the FS type which responds to changes pretty fast or instant, and checks the contents of $REPLY to make sure the fs is NFS [ ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/how-to-determine-what-filesystem-a-directory-exists-on ]

```
read -t1 < <(timeout 1 stat -f -c %T "/mnt/nfsshare/"  2>&-);if [[ ! "${REPLY}" =~ "nfs" ]];then echo "NFS mount NOT WORKING...";fi
```