# How can I use read timeouts with stat?

Tags: bash, nfs, stat, subshell, process-substitution

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -t1 < <(stat -t "/my/mountpoint")
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  echo NFS mount stale. Removing... 
  umount -f -l /my/mountpoint
fi
```

How do I mute the output of stat while at the same time being still able to detect its error level in the subsequent test?

Adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` inside the subshell, or in the end of the read line does not work. But there must be a way...

Thanks for any insights on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Command-Subsitution, Not Process Substitution

Instead of reading in from process subsitution, consider using command substitution instead. For example:

```
mountpoint=$(stat -t "/my/mountpoint" 2>&1)
```

This will silence the output by storing standard output in a variable, but leave the results retrievable by dereferencing *$mountpoint*. This approach also leaves the exit status accessible through *$?*.

### A Clearer Alternative

Alternatively, you might just rewrite this more simply as:

```
mountpoint="/my/mountpoint"
if stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-
then
    echo "NFS mount stale. Removing..."
    umount -f -l "$mountpoint"
fi
```

To me, this seems more intention-revealing and less error-prone, but your mileage may certainly vary.

### (Ab)using Read Timeouts

In the comments, the OP asked whether read timeouts could be abused to handle hung input from *stat*. The answer is yes, if you close standard error and check for an empty *$REPLY* string. For example:

```
mountpoint="/my/mountpoint"
read -t1 < <(stat -t "$mountpoint" 2>&-)
if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; then
    echo "NFS mount stale. Removing..."
    umount -f -l "$mountpoint"
fi
```

This works for several reasons:

1. When using the *read* builtin in Bash:

> If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.
>
> With standard error closed, *$REPLY* will be empty unless *stat* returns something on standard output, which it won't if it encounters an error. In other words, you're checking the **contents** of the *$REPLY* string instead of the exit status from *read*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to combine this with `read`? The reason it's there is to time out a command that would otherwise hang. This also happens with rpcinfo:

`read -t1 < <(rpcinfo -t 10.0.128.1 nfs)
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
 _RET=true
else
 _RET=false
fi`

If 10.0.128.1 is not reachable, rpcinfo by itself would hang for a few minutes. Redirection to `read` allows it to time out in 1 second  instead. It is specifically in this context–with `read`–that I'm having difficulty suppressing the output.

Comment: Heh.. okay, accepted! :) You posted the follow-up at the same time.

Comment: Also, I wasn't aware of read's REPLY variable.. very useful, thank you!

Comment: It seems an exit status still works even with **2>&-** in effect. The lines `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...` and `if [[ -n "$REPLY" ]] ; then ...` seem to work equally well when `read -t1` is used to time out the hung command, and 2>&- is used within the subshell to mute standard error (as in the example).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! The redirection mentioned in your response seems to work within the subshell without wiping out the return code like 2>&1 did. So this works as expected:

```
read -t1 < <(rpcinfo -t 10.0.128.1 nfs 2>&-)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "NFS server/service available!"
else
  echo "NFS server/service unavailable!"
fi
```

Where 10.0.128.1 is a 'bad' IP (no server/service responding). The script times out within a second and produces "NFS server/service unavailable!" response, but no output from rpcinfo. Likewise, when the IP is good, the desired response is output.

I upvoted your response!