# Running df -k command for my application server,and it is having mount issue,so need to trigger a mail

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I an running `df -k` command for my application server, and it is having mount issue.

So I need to trigger a mail saying that the server is having mount issue.

My basic question, I will write a shell script which will run `df -k` command and identify if the command takes long time to complete the command, then I need to trigger a mail.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What do you mean, *'mount issue'*? Are you perhaps talking about stale network (NFS?) mounts?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to archive; but timing how long a command takes is fairly easy, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

start=$(date +%s)
out=$(sleep 6)
took=$(($(date +%s) - $start))

if [ $took -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "$out" | mail -s "Command took too long" test@example.com
fi
```

**Edit**

This required the command to finish; if you want to have a timeout, I'd recommend using Python. It *is* possible with shell scripting, but IMHO this is much easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess, smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

proc = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '100'])
try:
    proc.wait(5)  # 5 is the timeout in seconds
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()

    # Send email
    msg = MIMEText("Command took too long\r\n")
    msg['Subject'] = 'Command took too long'
    msg['From'] = 'test@example.com'
    msg['To'] = 'test@example.com'
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail('test@example.com', ['test@example.com'], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Carpetsmoker.But this will work only when the command completed successfully,am i right?Mount issue is soming thing like some mount points are created in created to share the folder in the remote server.If the host server not able to connect to that remote server , the df -k command will keep loading without allowing us to type the next command.We manually need to use CTRL+C to kill the command.

Comment: @GopalKrishnan That's correct, I added an example with a timeout.

Comment: Hi Can you please let me know how to create a pythol file.what is the extension of hte file and how to run the file?

Comment: The usual extension is `.py`. And you can just use `python file.py`, or make it executable and use `./file.py`...

Comment: File "./mount_check_Allservers.sh", line 6, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['sh weblogic@web-preapp5 df -k', '100'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 621, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1126, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: The `args` argument isn't executed by the shell. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html). Perhaps you could add `shell=True`... Perhaps it would be even better to call a coworker who has more experience to look with you, since you seem to be *very* inexperienced in this area...

Answer (score 0):

This question lists ways to detect stale NFS mounts: [Is there a good way to detect a stale NFS mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643347/is-there-a-good-way-to-detect-a-stale-nfs-mount)

Select one solution and run it before the `df -k`.

Alternatively, you can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and then grep for the error pattern:

```
df -k 2>&1 | grep ...error...
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    ...send mail...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron.But this does'nt work.I used ssh web@web-slapp5 df -k | grep not.But i dont get any output.It got stucked in the df -k command itself.

Comment: Eventually, the `df` command will time out. And the code above needs to go into a single script which you have to invoke with `ssh`. Your code will run `df -k` remotely and then grep locally. If you want to avoid the wait, you need to look at the solutions behind the link.