# Timeout on subprocess readline in Python

Tags: python, timeout, subprocess

I have a small issue that I'm not quite sure how to solve. Here is a minimal example:

#### What I have

```
scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while(some_criterium):
    line = scan_process.stdout.readline()
    some_criterium = do_something(line)
```

#### What I would like

```
scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while(some_criterium):
    line = scan_process.stdout.readline()
    if nothing_happens_after_10s:
        break
    else:
        some_criterium = do_something(line)
```

I read a line from a subprocess and do something with it. How can I exit if no line arrived after a fixed time interval?

Comment: related: [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279)

Comment: related: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Comment: *whispers* criterion

Comment: @SteveCarter yes, the wording could  be improved. I would gladly accept  a corresponding edit.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers!

I found a way to solve my problem by simply using select.poll to peek into standard output.

```
import select
...
scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
poll_obj = select.poll()
poll_obj.register(scan_process.stdout, select.POLLIN)
while(some_criterium and not time_limit):
    poll_result = poll_obj.poll(0)
    if poll_result:
        line = scan_process.stdout.readline()
        some_criterium = do_something(line)
    update(time_limit)
```

Comment: while this appears to work, it's not robust -- consider if your child process outputs something without a new line. `select`/`poll` will trigger, but `readline` will block indefinitely.

Comment: May not work on Windows, where `select.poll()` only works for sockets. https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: I haven't tested the solution in Windows, so you might be right, I know it's working under OSX and Linux.

Comment: @gentimouton: [`asyncio` can read subprocess' output asynchroniously in a portable manner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34114767/4279)

Comment: @DimaTisnek, so if there is no line return at all, the program will still be blocked by the readline forever?

Comment: Tom's solution will block if the subprocess: outputs some text and does not output a new line and does not exit. The OP's intention (I think) was to hit a timeout in such case.

Comment: But sometimes `poll()` returns an empty list despite additional lines could be read. In my case.

Answer (score 32):

Here's a portable solution that enforces the timeout for reading a single line using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import sys
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

async def run_command(*args, timeout=None):
    # Start child process
    # NOTE: universal_newlines parameter is not supported
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args,
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    # Read line (sequence of bytes ending with b'\n') asynchronously
    while True:
        try:
            line = await asyncio.wait_for(process.stdout.readline(), timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
        else:
            if not line: # EOF
                break
            elif do_something(line):
                continue # While some criterium is satisfied
        process.kill() # Timeout or some criterion is not satisfied
        break
    return await process.wait() # Wait for the child process to exit


if sys.platform == "win32":
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() # For subprocess' pipes on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

returncode = loop.run_until_complete(run_command("cmd", "arg 1", "arg 2",
                                                 timeout=10))
loop.close()
```

Comment: This is awesome, great work!  I would suggest `process.stdout.read()` instead of `readline()` for someone else who may have more than just one expected line.

Comment: @jftuga: `.read()` would be incorrect here. The question is about `.readline()`. If you need all the output then it is simpler to use `.communicate()` with timeout. Read [my comment under the answer that uses `.communicate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756383/timeout-on-subprocess-readline-in-python/34114767?noredirect=1#comment55978734_10756738).

Comment: @JanKaifer yes. Both the link to Python 3 docs and the explicit shebang `#!... python3` point to Python 3. The current Python version is 3.6. The syntax in the answer is Python 3.5 (released in 2015).

Comment: This is great if you can switch everything you do to `asyncio`.  Want to interact with anything using `queue.Queue`? Tough, that breaks `asyncio`.  Got a non-`asyncio` library that you want to register a callback with?  Tough.  `asyncio` doesn't interact well with anything else and seems to almost always be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: @Tom: Unless it is not obvious, you can interact with the code that doesn't use `asyncio` from within your asyncio code e.g.,  [asyncio.to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) and yes, dealing with the async vs. blocking divide (having colored functions) is a general problem https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/

Comment: Calling `loop.run_until_complete()` inside a function makes the program return `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'run_command' was never awaited`. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: @secavfr: the code worked as is (last time I've tried). In 2022, I would replace everything starting with `if sys.platform` with just `asyncio.run(main())` where  inside `async def main()` you just `await run_command(..)`.

Answer (score 14):

I used something a bit more general in Python (if I remember correctly, also pieced together from Stack Overflow questions, but I cannot recall which ones).

```
import thread
from threading import Timer

def run_with_timeout(timeout, default, f, *args, **kwargs):
    if not timeout:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        timeout_timer = Timer(timeout, thread.interrupt_main)
        timeout_timer.start()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return default
    finally:
        timeout_timer.cancel()
```

Be warned, though. This uses an interrupt to stop whatever function you give it. This might not be a good idea for all functions and it also prevents you from closing the program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> during the timeout (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will be handled as a timeout).

You could use this and call it like:

```
scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while(some_criterium):
    line = run_with_timeout(timeout, None, scan_process.stdout.readline)
    if line is None:
        break
    else:
        some_criterium = do_something(line)
```

It might be a bit overkill, though. I suspect there is a simpler option for your case that I don't know.

Comment: it is not necessary to create a new thread for each line: [a single watchdog thread is enough](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115590/4279)

Comment: Works like a charm and should be picked as best :-) Thanks, @Flogo!

Comment: Isn't it better to put the first two lines inside try-block i.e. "timeout_timer = Timer( ....upto.... timer.start()" outside try-except?

Comment: @AshKetchum: the line `timeout_timer.start()` should be in the try-block. Imagine you have a very short time limit and there is a context switch after starting the thread and before entering the try-block. That could theoretically lead to a `KeyboardInterrupt` sent to the main thread. The line initializing the Timer could be outside, I guess.

Comment: Does not seem to work on Ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.9. Altough `_thread.interrupt_main()` gets executed, `scan_process.stdout.readline()` cannot be interrupted.

Comment: `interrupt_main` lives in the `_thread` module. Note the underscore,

Answer (score 8):

While [Tom's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756383/timeout-on-subprocess-readline-in-python/10759061#10759061) works, using `select()` in the [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) idiom is more compact, this is the equivalent of your answer:

```
from select import select
scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                bufsize=1)  # Line buffered
while some_criterium and not time_limit:
    poll_result = select([scan_process.stdout], [], [], time_limit)[0]
```

The rest is the same.

See `pydoc select.select`.

[Note: this is Unix-specific, as are some of the other answers.]

[Note 2: edited to add line buffering as per OP request]

[Note 3: the line buffering may not be reliable in all circumstances, leading to readline() blocking]

Comment: note: this as as well as @Tom's answer doesn't work on Windows and it resets the timeout if any input is received. OP wants to reset the timeout only if a newline is received (though it is straightforward to accommodate this requirement).

Comment: also, to avoid blocking on `.readline()` like in @Tom's answer, use `os.read(scan_process.stdout.fileno(), 512)` after the `select` (it is also not 100% percent safe if something else has access to the pipe) but it is less likely to block after the `select` than `.readline()`.

Comment: I thought the whole idea was to block until either a line is read or timeout has been reached?... sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: think: if your code is blocked on `readline()` then how do you expect to respect the timeout

Comment: it won't block because it's line buffered. select() won't return poll_result as True if there isn't a whole line ready to readline()

Comment: You don't know whether child's stdout is line-buffered (`bufsize=1` has no effect on the child process; it only regulates the buffer used in the parent to read the output) and typically the stdout is block-buffered if it is redirected to a pipe i.e., `select()` may return without the full line being available.

Answer (score 5):

Try using signal.alarm:

```
#timeout.py
import signal, sys

def timeout(sig, frm):
  print "This is taking too long..."
  sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout)
signal.alarm(10)
byte = 0

while 'IT' not in open('/dev/urandom').read(2):
  byte += 2
print "I got IT in %s byte(s)!" % byte
```

A couple of runs to show it works:

```
$ python timeout.py 
This is taking too long...
$ python timeout.py 
I got IT in 4672 byte(s)!
```

For a more detailed example, see [pGuides](http://pguides.net/python-tutorial/python-timeout-a-function/).

Comment: This is Unix-only, won't work on Windows as SIGALRM and signal.alarm are unavailable.

Comment: This is the simplest if you are unix-only and just need a way to bail out when something isn't happening as quickly as it should because somethings wrong (and works for any situation, not just reads).

Answer (score 5):

A portable solution is to use a thread to kill the child process if reading a line takes too long:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

timeout = 10
with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
           universal_newlines=True) as process:  # text mode
    # kill process in timeout seconds unless the timer is restarted
    watchdog = WatchdogTimer(timeout, callback=process.kill, daemon=True)
    watchdog.start()
    for line in process.stdout:
        # don't invoke the watcthdog callback if do_something() takes too long
        with watchdog.blocked:
            if not do_something(line):  # some criterium is not satisfied
                process.kill()
                break
            watchdog.restart()  # restart timer just before reading the next line
    watchdog.cancel()
```

where `WatchdogTimer` class is like `threading.Timer` that can be restarted and/or blocked:

```
from threading import Event, Lock, Thread
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from time import monotonic  # use time.time or monotonic.monotonic on Python 2

class WatchdogTimer(Thread):
    """Run *callback* in *timeout* seconds unless the timer is restarted."""

    def __init__(self, timeout, callback, *args, timer=monotonic, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.callback = callback
        self.args = args
        self.timer = timer
        self.cancelled = Event()
        self.blocked = Lock()

    def run(self):
        self.restart() # don't start timer until `.start()` is called
        # wait until timeout happens or the timer is canceled
        while not self.cancelled.wait(self.deadline - self.timer()):
            # don't test the timeout while something else holds the lock
            # allow the timer to be restarted while blocked
            with self.blocked:
                if self.deadline <= self.timer() and not self.cancelled.is_set():
                    return self.callback(*self.args)  # on timeout

    def restart(self):
        """Restart the watchdog timer."""
        self.deadline = self.timer() + self.timeout

    def cancel(self):
        self.cancelled.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using threading

```py
import subprocess, threading, time

def _watcher(proc, delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    proc.kill()

try:

    scan_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    threading.Thread(target = _watcher, args = (scan_process, 10)).start()
    
    while(some_criterium):
        line = scan_process.stdout.readline()
        if nothing_happens_after_10s:
            break
        else:
            some_criterium = do_something(line)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Please also refer
[How to run a process with timeout and still get stdout at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801202/how-to-run-a-process-with-timeout-and-still-get-stdout-at-runtime)