# How to implement a watchdog timer in Python?

Tags: python, watchdog

I would like to implement a simple watchdog timer in Python with two use cases:

- Watchdog ensures that a function doesn't execute longer than `x` seconds
- Watchdog ensures that certain regularly executed function does indeed execute at least every `y` seconds

How do I do that?

Comment: Here's [`WatchdogTimer` implementation that creates only one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115590/4279)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just publishing my own solution to this:

```
from threading import Timer

class Watchdog(Exception):
    def __init__(self, timeout, userHandler=None):  # timeout in seconds
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.handler = userHandler if userHandler is not None else self.defaultHandler
        self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)
        self.timer.start()

    def reset(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)
        self.timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.cancel()

    def defaultHandler(self):
        raise self
```

Usage if you want to make sure function finishes in less than `x` seconds:

```
watchdog = Watchdog(x)
try:
  # do something that might take too long
except Watchdog:
  # handle watchdog error
watchdog.stop()
```

Usage if you regularly execute something and want to make sure it is executed at least every `y` seconds:

```
import sys

def myHandler():
  print "Whoa! Watchdog expired. Holy heavens!"
  sys.exit()

watchdog = Watchdog(y, myHandler)

def doSomethingRegularly():
  # make sure you do not return in here or call watchdog.reset() before returning
  watchdog.reset()
```

Comment: Ever heard of PEP8? And what is `Timer()` here?

Comment: Nope, haven't heard about it. I am beginner. But I will check once I have more time for this...

Comment: I'm not sure about your `reset` method. In your `__init__` your `Timer` switches based on if `userHandler` (which should be `is not None` BTW) is supplied, in which case it's used. In `reset` - it's always `self.handler` that will then be used...

Comment: applied PEP8, fixed bug in reset. Thanks.

Comment: There is also the [`signal module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example) and [`signal.alarm`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) could be used for a timer.

Comment: I think the `__init__` function and `reset` function need to call [`self.timer.start()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects).

Comment: [This answer for handling timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348885/758174) is better (and can be used in a `with` context).

Comment: This `Watchdog` raises the `Exception` (itself) in a separate thread (the `Timer` thread), so the `try`/`except` in the usage example is useless. The `Watchdog` also does not interrupt the long operation, which would be the point of a watchdog.

Comment: Confirmed @rtoijala comment.  This should not be the selected answer since it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`signal.alarm()` sets a timeout for your program, and you can call it in your main loop, and set it to the greater of the two times you are prepared to tolerate:

```
import signal
while True:
    signal.alarm(10)
    infloop()
```

Comment: assuming that the interpreter runs on a platform which implements POSIX signals.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wdt I use in my app without class. It has no way to stop it:

```
from threading import Event, Thread

def wdt(time, callback):
    # a reset flag
    reset_e = Event()
    # a function to reset the wdt
    def reset(): reset_e.set()
    # the function to run in a differen thread
    def checker():
        # check if reset flag is set.
        # wait for specified time to give chance to reset.
        while reset_e.wait(time):
            # it was set in time. clear and wait again
            reset_e.clear()
        # time run out.
        callback()
    # the event is not set by default. Set it
    reset()
    # create and start the wdt
    t = Thread(target=checker)
    t.start()
    # return the resetter
    return reset


# The callback to run if wdt is not reset
def bark():
    print('woof')       

# Test
import time
reset = wdt(1.0, bark)
time.sleep(0.9)
reset()
time.sleep(2.0)
```