# How does this watchdog function work?

Tags: python, watchdog

This is from an example found on this site.
I am not clear on when the `Watchdog` function is executed in the except clause. In my opinion this will never be executed unless there is an error. What am I missing?

```
from threading import Timer
import time
class Watchdog:
    def __init__(self, timeout, userHandler=None):  # timeout in seconds
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.handler = userHandler if userHandler is not None else self.defaultHandler
        self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)

    def reset(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.handler)

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.cancel()

    def defaultHandler(self):
        raise self


watchdog = Watchdog(2)
watchdog.timer.start()
x=1
try:
  # do something that might take too long
  while x>0:
    print "test"
    time.sleep(0.2)
except watchdog:
  # handle watchdog error
  watchdog.stop()
```

Comment: It's basically a trick for terminating code that is taking a long time to execute.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: it seems `self.timer.start()` is missing

Comment: where do I place that? Placing that just after instantiating Watchdog did not work. It did rise an error but it did not break the loop

Comment: Could you give the reference of where you found that code. It seems to be incomplete

Comment: @Serge-Ballesta  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148735/how-to-implement-a-watchdog-timer-in-python