# Timeout (and skip) a block of code inside a python iteration

Tags: python

How can I skip and continue when a step of a loop takes too long?

Below are a few desirable interfaces I'd like:

```py
for x in some_collection:
    with Timeout(2.5):  # time out after 2.5 seconds
        do_something(x)
```

Would be nice (and even better -- but might be harder):

```py
with TimeoutLoopStep(2.5):  # time out after 2.5 seconds
    for x in some_collection:
        do_something(x)
```

Possibly an equivalent `timeout_loop_step` decorator to consume iterators in that manner:

```py
timeout_loop_step(2.5)(map(do_something, some_collection))
```

--- Addendum (edit) to dispel some ambiguity ---

What I'm looking for is a context manager and/or decorator that will interrupt the processing of a step of an iteration if it lasts too long.

Most APIs that talk to a remote system (e.g. DBs) provide some sort of `timeout` parameter that means *"do this, but if you exceed `timeout` trying, just phorgetaboutit and move on to the next item..."*

But if I'm not offered such control, I'd like to achieve it, externally, with a reusable context manager or decorator.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148735/how-to-implement-a-watchdog-timer-in-python 
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a watchdog timer in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148735/how-to-implement-a-watchdog-timer-in-python)

Comment: @Steve, your link is the same as Tom's first link.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn, the second is not what I'm looking for. The first might, but I'd need to try to put it in one of the forms I mentioned in my question to see if it actually works. I'll Add more details to my question to make it clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: No the `Timer` solution (WatchDog) is not a solution. Timer docs say "Call a function after a specified number of seconds". In contrast what I want is a means to "interrupt the call of a function after a specified number of seconds".

Comment: @thorwhalenn - yes. the system put that there automatically when I marked this question as a duplicate.  If I'd thought about it, I would have deleted it, knowing that Tom already listed it. Obviously not a big deal either way.

Answer (score 1):

I needed  something similar long back. My solution was a thread based iterator decorator kind of thing.
I had put it on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/iterators/) by the name `iterators`.
For your case it would look like this.

```
from iterators import TimeoutIterator

m = map(do_something, some_collection)
it = TimeoutIterator(m, timeout=2.5)

for x in it:
  if x == None: # gives None if there is a timeout
    it.interrupt() # stop the underlying thread if breaking the loop
    break
```

Alternatively if the result of your function itself can be None then you could use something  like this:

```
from iterators import TimeoutIterator

m = map(do_something, some_collection)
it = TimeoutIterator(m, timeout=2.5,  sentinel=object())

for x in it:
  if x == it.get_sentinel(): # gives the sentinal object if there is a timeout
    it.interrupt()  # stop the underlying thread
    break
```

The code may look verbose as unfortunately the idea of using a context handler to stop underlying thread never came to my mind. That would have removed the need of calling interrupt. I'll add it in a new release.
For my case I needed to continue iterating till end of actual iterator, but still  be able to identify whether I get a result or a timeout. So calling interrupt  manually was never needed.

Checkout other options and examples in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time` module:

```
import time

time_out = time.time()+2.5
for x in some_collection:
    if time.time() == time_out:
        break
    do_something(x)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about a "lean" way to interrupt a process. What trying to do above is a pause, which you'd better do using `time.sleep(2.5)`. Also, your code will often never terminate. What you meant to say was `if time.time() >= time_out` I think.