# How to execute a code for a given time period

Tags: python, time, timer, task

I want to know if there is a way in python 2.7 to run code for just for a given time, like 3600 seconds. The time can variate from one execution to an other. 
 Any ideas are welcome since I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: You may want to consider adding a timeout to subprocess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout

Comment: its not clear what your asking... are you launching with subroccess ? you can do `if time.time()-starttime > somevalue:return` in side of a loop in a function...

Comment: related: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow to interrupt the computations for any reason:

```
def compute_something(stopped):
    while not stopped:
        # continue computations

stopped = []
threading.Timer(3600, stopped.append, args=[True]).start()
compute_something(stopped)
```