# Killing a script launched in a Process via os.system()

Tags: python, process, os.system

I have a python script which launches several processes. Each process basically just calls a shell script:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import logging

def thread_method(n = 4):
    global logger
    command = "~/Scripts/run.sh " + str(n) + " >> /var/log/mylog.log"
    if (debug): logger.debug(command)
    os.system(command)
```

I launch several of these threads, which are meant to run in the background. I want to have a timeout on these threads, such that if it exceeds the timeout, they are killed:

```
t = []
for x in range(10):
    try:
        t.append(Process(target=thread_method, args=(x,) ) )
        t[-1].start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error: unable to start thread")
        logger.error("Error message: " + str(e))
logger.info("Waiting up to 60 seconds to allow threads to finish")
t[0].join(60)
for n in range(len(t)):
    if t[n].is_alive():
    logger.info(str(n) + " is still alive after 60 seconds, forcibly terminating")
     t[n].terminate()
```

The problem is that calling terminate() on the process threads isn't killing the launched run.sh script - it continues running in the background until I either force kill it from the command line, or it finishes internally. Is there a way to have terminate also kill the subshell created by os.system()?

Answer (score 4):

You should use an event to signal the worker to terminate, run the subprocess with `subprocess` module, then terminate it with `Popen.terminate()`. Calling `Process.terminate()` will not allow it worker to clean up. See [the documentation for `Process.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate).

Comment: you confuse subprocess.Popen.terminate and multiprocessing.Process.terminate

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But `multiprocessing.Process.terminate()` doesn't allow the process it controls to clean up. What I mean is to use an event to terminate `multiprocessing`'s worker so it can clean up and call `subprocess.Popen.terminate()` on the subprocess the worker is controlling.

Comment: You're right. I've just ignored that part of the question because [the answer doesn't require neither threads (`threading`) nor processes (`multiprocessing`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12322399/4279).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) instead, whose objects have a [`terminate()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) explicitly for this.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.3, the subprocess module supports a timeout: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html

For other solutions regarding Python 2.x, please have a look in this thread: [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279):

```
import os
import time
from subprocess import Popen

def start_process(n, stdout):
    # no need for `global logger` you don't assign to it
    command = [os.path.expanduser("~/Scripts/run.sh"), str(n)]
    logger.debug(command) # no need for if(debug); set logging level instead
    return Popen(command, stdout=stdout) # run directly

# no need to use threads; Popen is asynchronous 
with open('/tmp/scripts_output.txt') as file:
    processes = [start_process(i, file) for i in range(10)]

    # wait at most timeout seconds for the processes to complete
    # you could use p.wait() and signal.alarm or threading.Timer instead
    endtime = time.time() + timeout
    while any(p.poll() is None for p in processes) and time.time() < endtime:
        time.sleep(.04)

    # terminate unfinished processes
    for p in processes:
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.terminate()
            p.wait() # blocks if `kill pid` is ignored
```

Use `p.wait(timeout)` if it is available.