# Using python Popen to read the last line

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, pipe

I have a simple python program:

test.py:

```
import time
for i in range(100000):
    print i
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I want to use another program that executes the above one in order to read the last line output while the above program is counting.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("test",stdout=PIPE)
sleep(20) # sleeps an arbitrary time
print stdout.readlines()[-1]
```

The problem is that `process.stdout.readlines()` waits until test.py finishes execution. 
Is there any way to read the last line that has been writen in the output while the program is executing?

Comment: If your "test" program is also written in python, you should consider using threads and pass information from one side to the other instead of printing and reading from a file...

Comment: @JBernardo Thanks for the suggestion, but im what im trying to archieve is to make it work for any program.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `collections.deque` to save only the last specified number of lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import collections
import subprocess
import time
import threading

def read_output(process, append):
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
        append(line)

def main():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["program"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # save last `number_of_lines` lines of the process output
    number_of_lines = 1
    q = collections.deque(maxlen=number_of_lines)
    t = threading.Thread(target=read_output, args=(process, q.append))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    #
    time.sleep(20)

    # print saved lines
    print ''.join(q),
    # process is still running
    # uncomment if you don't want to wait for the process to complete
    ##process.terminate() # if it doesn't terminate; use process.kill()
    process.wait()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

See [other tail-like solutions that print only the portion of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279)

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) if your child program uses a block-buffering (instead of line-bufferring) for its stdout while running non-interactively.

Comment: Nice answer, but sadly im having the same problem that I stated before. It only displays output if the called process has finished

Comment: I believe in `test.py` Python is buffering the output sent to `sys.stdout`. I got this solution to work by using the `-u` flag: `python -u test.py`. (Otherwise the output is empty.)

Comment: @unutbu: yes. I've forgot to mention it. I've added the link that provides some workarounds

Comment: @AlejandroGarcia: You can avoid the IOError by putting `process.terminate()` at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly trivial with [sh.py](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/):

```
import sh

def process_line(line):
    print line

process = sh.python("test.py", _out=process_line)
process.wait()
```