# hcitool lescan subprocess python do not produce output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem with sub-process code. The `subprocess.Popen()` works fine but when I try to read its output through `stdout.read()` there is no value to read.

```
**import os
import signal
import subprocess
import threading
import sys
import commands

print commands.getoutput("hcitool dev")
print 'down'
commands.getoutput('hciconfig hci1 down')
print 'up'
commands.getoutput('hciconfig hci1 up')
commands.getoutput('killall hcitool')
stop = False
ping = subprocess.call('hcitool lescan', shell = False,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,executable='/bin/bash')
for i in ping.stdout:
    print i

def kill():
    global stop
    stop = True
    os.kill(ping.pid, signal.SIGTERM)

threading.Timer(5, kill).start()

#while not stop:
#   print 'now in while not loop'
#   sys.stdout.write(ping.stdout.read(1))

print 'trying to print stdout'
out, err = ping.communicate()
print "out",out

#result = out.decode()

print "Result : ",result**
```

This code works fine when I change `hcitool lescan` to ping www.google.com, and produces output but when I try with `hcitool lescan` it either hangs forever or produces no output. Help is appreciated!

Comment: related: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Answer (score 5):

Any of the above answers didn't work for me. Was hung up in the forever scan of hcitool. So finally i wrote a shell script and called it by my python code. This is working fine for me and i am reading the output from the file "result.txt".

```
hcitool lescan>result.txt &  
sleep 5  
pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code e.g., `subprocess.call()` returns an integer (exit status of the program) and an integer has no `.stdout` attribute; also the combination of `shell=False` and non-None `executable` is very rarely useful (and it is probably used incorrectly in this case).

The simplest way to fix the code is to use `check_output()`:

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx

output = qx(["hcitool", "lescan"]) # get all output at once
print output,
```

As an alternative, you could print program's output line by line as soon as its stdout is flushed:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["hcitool", "lescan"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1) # start process
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''): # read output line-by-line
    print line,
# reached EOF, nothing more to read
proc.communicate() # close `proc.stdout`, wait for child process to terminate
print "Exit status", proc.returncode
```

To kill a subprocess, you could use its `.kill()` method e.g.:

```
from threading import Timer

def kill(process):
    try:
        process.kill()
        process.wait() # to avoid zombies
    except OSError: # ignore errors
        pass 

Timer(5, kill, [proc]).start() # kill in 5 seconds
```

Comment: thank you for ans,your first method do not work,because [hcitool lescan] has never-lasting output,i.e it's a infinite loop and first line produces error:as hcitool lescan returned exit status 1:

Comment: @MoinakhtarSalman: Only one of the two can be true at the same time: either "hcitool lescan" has never-lasting output or it ends with the exit status `1`. What results do you get with the second code example if you add `Timer(5, kill, [proc]).start()` before `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):` line?

Comment: @sebastian.second code work's perfect.as i mentioned,check out my ans below.

Comment: @MoinakhtarSalman: if you want the first 30 lines of child's output instead of killing it on timeout then you could use `first30lines = list(islice(iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''), 30)); kill(proc)`

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much..but the problem is hcitool lescan never stops,and hence hangs out in the very next line of your code.,
and i found similar solution here it is.this works fine and i dont have to kill subprocess,this code takes some extra time to pour output,but this following code works preciesly,

```
from os import kill
import signal
import subprocess
import threading
import tempfile
import sys
import time
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import commands
t = TemporaryFile()
global pipe_output
print commands.getoutput("hcitool dev")
print 'down'
commands.getoutput('hciconfig hci0 down')
print 'up'
commands.getoutput('hciconfig hci0 up')
print commands.getoutput("hcitool dev")
commands.getoutput('killall hcitool')
p = subprocess.Popen('hcitool lescan', bufsize = 0,shell = True, stdout =subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
time.sleep(10)
#os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGTERM)
for i in range(0,30,1):
    print 'for'
    inchar = p.stdout.readline()
    i+=1
    if inchar:
        print 'loop num:',i
        print str(inchar)
        t.write(str(inchar))
print 'out of loop'
t.seek(0)
print t.read()
```

any help how to reduce waiting time,other than just changing time.sleep() ,is appreciated
thank you all

Comment: don't ask additional questions in the answer; you could update your question, ask a new one instead. See [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198) to fix the delay in the output. Note: `time.sleep(10)` is useless here; `p.stdout.readline()` blocks until something is available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use Popen class instead of the call class. hcitool lescan will run forever. subprocess.call waits for the call to be finished to return. Popen does not wait.