# In python, how can I use timeout in subprocess *and* get the output

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, subprocess

I used the code in these 2 question

[how to get the return value from a thread in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

[subprocess with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

And got this

```c
import subprocess, threading, os

class ThreadWithReturnValue(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, Verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs, Verbose)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._Thread__target is not None:
            self._return = self._Thread__target(*self._Thread__args, **self._Thread__kwargs)

    def join(self, timeout = None):
        threading.Thread.join(self, timeout)
        return self._return

class SubprocessWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, cmd, timeout):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None
        self.timeout = timeout
    def run(self):
        def target(cmd):
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
            returnValue = self.process.communicate()
            return [returnValue[0], returnValue[1], self.process.returncode]

        thread = ThreadWithReturnValue(target=target, args=[self.cmd])
        thread.start()
        returnValue = thread.join(self.timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print 'cmd = ',self.cmd
            self.process.kill()
            returnValue = thread.join()
            print 'rc = ', returnValue[2]
        output = returnValue[0]
        error = returnValue[1]
        rc = returnValue[2]
        return (output, rc)

os.system('date +%T.%N')
s1 = SubprocessWrapper("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'", timeout = 3)
s1.run()
os.system('date +%T.%N')
s2 = SubprocessWrapper("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'", timeout = 1)
s2.run()
os.system('date +%T.%N')
```

The problem is that the output is

```
11:20:34.963947950
11:20:36.986685289
cmd =  echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'
rc =  -9
11:20:38.995597397
```

So you can see the process which was supposed to be terminated after one second actually took 2 seconds. This happens because of the `join()` but in the question `subprocess with timeout` this works fine. This means that when I integrated both codes I caused this problem, my question is how to fix it? I was thinking that I might need to call `threading.Thread.__init__` method in a different way but I can't understand how.

Comment: Time is a tricky thing. For a computer time is measured in vibrations of a crystal. For you it is measured in seconds, which is based on the swing of a pendulum. When you tell a computer to sleep for 2 seconds, it tries to sleep in user-time, but it has to sleep in computer time, since it doesn't know what user-time is. Sometimes when this happens, you get small differences, so when dealing with such small time quantities, you can't be sure there is a real problem. Try it with 100 seconds and see what happens. There is a way to make the timing much better, but you will have to ask a new one.

Comment: related: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Comment: @InbarRose: a second is ages in computer terms (billions of operations)

Comment: Yes, but when the device which lets the user know how many user-seconds have passed is petitioned, it has a very strict mapping, a single operation over 1 second is counted as 2 seconds. which when dealing with such small numbers is a 100% increase in time. If you want to run something for 100 seconds, and it runs for 101 seconds, its only a 1% increase in time (even though its not really increasing, just looks like it is)

Comment: @InbarRose, I used a longer fraction of time as well, it doesn't matter, after the timeout expires `join` waits until `subprocess` is finished, while in the original question this wasn't the case

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you got the right answer, `stop reading process output in python without hang` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @e271p314: test it first. Some solutions in the answer will return in 2 seconds instead of 1.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, already did, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't return output in one second despite the timeout. It returns it in two seconds after the sleep:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import TimeoutExpired, check_output as qx
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()
try:
    qx("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'",
       shell=True, universal_newlines=True, timeout=1)
except TimeoutExpired as e:
    print("Got %r in %.2f seconds" % (e.output, timer() - start))
else:
    assert 0 # should not get here
```

#### Output

```
Got 'Process started\n' in 2.00 seconds
```

Alarm-based solution from ["Stop reading process output in Python without hang?" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279) works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from timeit import default_timer as timer

class Alarm(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Alarm

start = timer()
# start process
process = Popen("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'",
                shell=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

# set signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
signal.alarm(1) # produce SIGALRM in a second
buf = []
try:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
        buf.append(line) # assume it is atomic
except Alarm:
    process.kill()
else:
    signal.alarm(0) # reset alarm
finally:
    output = ''.join(buf)
print("Got %r in %.2f seconds" % (output, timer() - start))
process.stdout.close()
process.wait()
```

#### Output

```
Got 'Process started\n' in 1.00 seconds
```

Comment: @e271p314: Timer-based solution returns in 2 seconds instead of 1 [in my tests](https://gist.github.com/7453163)