# How to kill a process been created by subprocess in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

Under Linux Ubuntu operating system, I run the `test.py` scrip which contain a `GObject` loop using `subprocess` by:

```
subprocess.call(["test.py"])
```

Now, this `test.py` will creat process. Is there a way to kill this process in Python?
Note: I don't know the process ID.

I am sorry if I didn't explain my problem very clearly as I am new to this forms and new to python in general.

Comment: Is this works? `p = subprocess.call(["test.py"]);p.kill()`.

Comment: No it gives me : `AttributeError: int object has no attribute kill`

Comment: here's related (more complex) case: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not to use `subprocess.call` but construct a `Popen` object and use its API: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

In particular:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call()` is just `subprocess.Popen().wait()`:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from threading import Timer

p = Popen(["command", "arg1"])
print(p.pid) # you can save pid to a file to use it outside Python

# do something else..

# now ask the command to exit
p.terminate()
terminator = Timer(5, p.kill) # give it 5 seconds to exit; then kill it
terminator.start()
p.wait()
terminator.cancel() # the child process exited, cancel the hit
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` waits for the process to be completed and returns the exit code (integer) value , hence there is no way of knowing the process id of the child process. YOu should consider using `subprocess.Popen` which forks() child process.