# Python Subprocess Finishes, but Output File Not Available

Tags: python, subprocess

My python code is using a subprocess to call "ifconfig" through the shell and uses ">"  to write the output to a text file. When the subprocess finishes, and returns success, I read the output file. I do this at fixed intervals to monitor the network status, but occasionally I'm unable to open the output file. I was just reading that Popen has optional arguments for stdout and stderr, which may be safer/better supported, but I'm curious to why my current version fails. My code is below. There are a few objects and macros from my library included without explanation, but I think the code is still clear enough for this question.

Why does opening the output file occasionally fail? Is it possible the file is not ready when the subprocess returns? What would be a way to guarantee it's ready to open?

```
       # Build command line expression.
        expr = 'ifconfig' + ' >' + outputFile + ' 2>&1'

        try:
            # Execute command line expression.
            p = subprocess.Popen(expr, shell=True)
        except:
            Error("Unable to open subprocess.")

        if(p is None):
            Error("Unable to create subprocess.")

        # Wait until command line expression has been executed.
        wait = Wait.Wait(Constants.MIN_TIME_TO_QUERY_NETWORK_INFO, Constants.MAX_TIME_TO_QUERY_NETWORK_INFO)

        #Execute command then wait for timeout.    
        if (wait.StopUntilCondition(operator.ne, (p.poll,), None, True)):
            p.kill()
            Error("Get subnet mask subprocess timed out.")

        if(not p.poll() == 0):
            Error("Failed to get network information from operating system.")

        Warning("About to read output file from get subnet mask...")

        # Read temporary output file.
        f = open(outputFile, "r")
        networkInfo = f.read()
        f.close()
```

Comment: I wonder: does the call to `Popen` wait for `ifconfig` to exit, or does it wait for the redirect to finish?

Comment: unrelated: don't: `if(not p.poll() == 0):`, do `if p.poll() != 0:`, though you should use `p.wait()` here instead

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for that note on "not ==" vs "!=". I'd never considered that and now know there's a difference. Regarding "if(p.poll() != 0)", the documentation says that "p.poll()" checks if the process has terminated (returns None until finished, which my wait.StopUntilCondition waits for) and "p.wait()" waits til the process has terminated. Seems the same, but I'll probably go with your "check_output" answer anyways. Thanks!

Comment: please, do not use unnecessary parens (Python is not C). `p.wait()` (unlike `p.poll()`) asserts that the process is finished.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Will do on the parentheses...hard to break the habit. As for p.poll() vs p.wait(), the documentation doesn't seem to specify that, but I'll take your word there's an assertion buried in there somewhere. The documentation for p.wait says "Wait for child process to terminate. " and for p.poll "Check if child process has terminated.".

Comment: I meant that after `p.poll() != 0` the process may be still running (`p.poll()` returns `None` in this case) but after `p.wait() != 0` we know that it has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the corrupted/missing output, you should call `p.wait()` before trying to read the file. You don't need to use a file in this case:

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

network_info = check_output('ifconfig', stderr=STDOUT)
```

If you want to interrupt `ifconfig` before it is done *and* read its output; see [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to just use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and write that output to a file yourself. Note that if you want to capture both stdout and stderr you cannot use `subprocess.check_output`

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    outdata, errdata = p.communicate()
except Exception as e:
    print "An error occurred:", e
with open(outputFile, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(outdata)
```

With this you don't have to wait; `communicate` won't return before the process is finished.

If you just want to capture stdout, use `subprocess.check_output` instead;

```
try:
    outdata = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig'])
except Exception as e:
    print "An error occurred:", e
with open(outputFile, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(outdata)
```

Comment: -1: `check_output` **can** be used to capture both stdout and stderr (it is shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23068971/4279)).