# Gather constant output from process (Python)

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, bluez

I have a program that generates constant output (`hcitool lescan`):

```
CC:41:00:4D:AA:AA Name1
CC:41:00:4D:AA:BB Name2
CC:41:00:4D:AA:CC Name3
```

I would like to parse this output in `Python` constantly, but **after few seconds I want to kill the process**.
As it has to be terminated manually (by pressing `CTRL-C`), I cannot use `subprocess.check_value(["prog"])`. Also calling `p = subprocess.Popen(["prog"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` isn't good, as it orders `Popen` to read this to the `EOF`. Also, such call hangs the `Python` script.

My question is: How can I start a program in `Python` (can be limited to `Linux` environment) and terminate it after few seconds while gathering it's output (from `stdout`)?

Comment: can you check for special "control word" something like "quit"?

Comment: related: [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279)

Comment: calling `p = Popen(["prog"], stdout=PIPE)` DOES NOT order `Popen` to read until `EOF`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Your link works like a charm. Could lock down this question and add reference to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417962/stop-reading-process-output-in-python-without-hang

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your program is doing, you could use a couple of methods.

The first one would be to put the process in a while loop and check for the MAC address in the lescan output file.

```
import os

tag = 0
while tag != "00:11:22:33:44:55":
    open("file.txt","w").close()
    os.system("hcitool lescan> file.txt"+" & pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool")
    f = open("file.txt","r")
    read = f.read()
    if "00:11:22:33:44:55" in read:
        print "found"
        tag = "00:11:22:33:44:55"
print "program finished"
os._exit(0)
```

The second solution would be if you are using `lescan` and `hcidump` at the same time.

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

d = subprocess.Popen(["sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates & sudo hcidump -w dump.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
time.sleep(3)
dump = os.system("sudo hcidump -r dump.txt>scan.txt")
#read the file like the previous solution I shown you
print "program finished"
os._exit(0)
```

The best way I found to do this was to output your readings to a file and the scan the file for any specific thing your are looking for.

Comment back if you need anything specific, though I think I have covered your question.

Comment: 1. your 1st solution with `os.system()` call kills `hcitool` *immediately*. It is not very useful. 2. I don't know what are you trying to achieve by using `hcidump` here but don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from the pipe 3. Don't use `shell=True` unless you need it. 4. Remove `os._exit(0)`, it does the wrong thing here e.g., it doesn't flush stdout and it is unnecessary here. 5. [here're possible alternative solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279).

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as the subprocess you are running are continuously producing output. You can end it anytime with Ctrl-C.

(Incorporated J.F. Sebastian's sensible suggestions)

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['hcitool', 'lescan'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)

try:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
        print line, # Do watever processing you want to do here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p.kill()

p.wait()
p.stdout.close()
```

Comment: This is bad coding practice, @Melon clearly stated he wanted to have a timer and then for the program to stop, after a certain amount of seconds. MEANING, that the program should be AUTOMATED with NO keyboard input.

Comment: That is not how I read his questions. I interpreted it as he wanted to be able to stop it after a few seconds. Maybe I misunderstood. Either way, I don't see what that has to do with coding practices.

Comment: Killing a program with CTRL-C is bad practice, all programs should be self-efficient and terminate at the right time. `os._exit(0)` quits any program after it has finished its processes, without the use of CTRL-C. @Moose

Comment: You are not killing the Python program. It can happily continue to run. You are sending an interrupt, telling it to kill the subprocess. I can see lots of use for that.

Comment: @JonathanDavies: OP mistakenly thinks that `Ctrl-C` is mandatory to kill the child process in a few seconds. Therefore @Moose answer is (incorrect but) possible interpretation of the question

Comment: @Moose: 1. don't use `shell=True` and the list argument (drop `shell=True`). 2. use `print line,` (note: the trailing comma) to avoid doubling newlines. 3. Add `p.wait()` at the end, to avoid zombies. 4. Add `bufsize=1` -- [it might make a difference sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279). 5. Add `p.stdout.close()` after the loop for proper cleanup.