# Processing a PIPE inside Python - Raspbian Linux

Tags: python, linux, pipe, subprocess, raspbian

Folks....I have a script running in a Python program via a `subprocess Popen` 
command to create a pipe with the output from the script.  It is working.  However I thought I would have to use the `.communicate()` command to process records in the pipe from my program.  I was not able to get that working, but did get it working with this code.  What did I do wrong when I tried to use the `.communicate` command?

```
import subprocess
nul_f = open('/dev/null', 'w') 
try:
  tcpdmp = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -A -n -p -l -             i eth0 -s0 -w - tcp dst port 80'], 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True,
                    stderr=nul_f,)
  print 'My Records'
  i=0
#  end_of_pipe = tcpdmp.communicate()
  while i<10:
    i=i+1
    line = tcpdmp.stdout.readline()
    print '\t --', i, line
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print 'done'
tcpdmp.terminate()
tcpdmp.kill()
nul_f.close()
```

Thanks for any suggestions and critiques.....RDK

ps...Running Raspbian Linux on a Raspberry pi....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.communicate()` **waits** for the child process to end. `tcpdump` does not end peacefully that is why your code has `except KeyboardInterrupt` (to handle Ctrl+C).

Unrelated: you could replace the while loop with this:

```
from itertools import islice

for line in enumerate(islice(iter(tcpdump.stdout.readline, b''), 10), start=1):
    print '\t --', i, line, #NOTE: comma at the end to avoid double newlines
```

See also, [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Comment: JF....OK, thanks for the explanation, the reference and the alternate code....RDK