# Python subprocess.call tar command to use the uncompressed files later

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, subprocess

I'm trying to uncompress a tar file with .gz extension

```
status = subprocess.call('tar -zvxf %s -C %s 2> /dev/null' % (zipped_tar_file,data_path), shell=True)
```

Shortly after this statement, I have another call-

```
status = subprocess.call('psql -q -v PATH=%s -f %s -h %s -p %d %s' %(some params)
```

The second statement tells postgres to use some files extracted by the first command. I get a file not exists error in postgres.

It looks like the tar command is still running while the second statement has started and postgres can't find the required files which are yet to be extracted.

```
ERROR:  could not open file "path/filename.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

`filename.csv` is one of the files to be extracted from the tarball.

The files are a bit heavy (few hundered of megabytes)

Is this the correct way to use `subprocess.call`?

Answer (score 0):

As subprocess.call() taking time to execute you can add time delay between execution of two commands.

You can check: [Python subprocess timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733270/python-subprocess-timeout) for more detailed answer.