# How to limit program's execution time when using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, kill

I want to use subprocess to run a program and I need to limit the execution time. For example, I want to kill it if it runs for more than 2 seconds.

For common programs, kill() works well. But if I try to run `/usr/bin/time something`, kill() can’t really kill the program.

My code below seems doesn’t work well. The program is still running.

```
import subprocess
import time

exec_proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/time -f \"%e\\n%M\" ./son > /dev/null", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True)

max_time = 1
cur_time = 0.0
return_code = 0
while cur_time <= max_time:
    if exec_proc.poll() != None:
        return_code = exec_proc.poll()
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)
    cur_time += 0.1

if cur_time > max_time:
    exec_proc.kill()
```

Comment: duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like so in your command line:

```
perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' <timeout> <your_command>
```

this will run the command `<your_command>` and terminate it in `<timeout>` second.

a dummy example :

```
# set time out to 5, so that the command will be killed after 5 second 
command = ['perl', '-e', "'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV'", "5"]

command += ["ping", "www.google.com"]

exec_proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

or you can use the [signal.alarm](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.alarm)() if you want it with python but it's the same.

Comment: Answering a Python question with Perl, nice…

Comment: It works well, but when I try "perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' 3 /usr/bin/time ping google.com", the program won't stop.

Comment: why not do : __time perl -e 'alarm shift @ARGV; exec @ARGV' 3  ping google.com__ ???

Comment: @jleedev : what ??? Perl, python, ruby, shell .... programming language are just a tool, you can also comment on the answer that have been posted because it use shell !!!!!

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Python 2.6 or later, you can use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    # Stuff to run your process here

p = Process(target=f)
p.start()
p.join(timeout)
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
```

---

Actually, multiprocessing is the wrong module for this task since it is just a way to control how long a thread runs.  You have no control over any children the thread may run.  As singularity suggests, using [signal.alarm](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) is the normal approach.

```
import signal
import subprocess

def handle_alarm(signum, frame):
    # If the alarm is triggered, we're still in the exec_proc.communicate()
    # call, so use exec_proc.kill() to end the process.
    frame.f_locals['self'].kill()

max_time = ...
stdout = stderr = None
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handle_alarm)
exec_proc = subprocess.Popen(['time', 'ping', '-c', '5', 'google.com'],
                             stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
signal.alarm(max_time)
try:
    (stdout, stderr) = exec_proc.communicate()
except IOError:
    # process was killed due to exceeding the alarm
finally:
    signal.alarm(0)
# do stuff with stdout/stderr if they're not None
```

Comment: # Try it. After 3 seconds, ping is still running.
import subprocess
import time

from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    exec_proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/time ping google.com", shell = True)

p = Process(target=f)
p.start()
p.join(3)
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()

time.sleep(10)

Comment: You're right.  `p.terminate()` only kills the thread, not any children that were spawned.  I don't see why you're using `shell = True` so I'll update my answer with a solution using signal.alarm as singularity suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I use os.kill() but am not sure if it works on all OSes.
Pseudo code follows, and see [Doug Hellman](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess)'s page.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['google-chrome'])                                               
os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGUSR1)</code>
```