# Run python code for a specified amount of time and recover results

Tags: python, time

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616580/run-external-python-program-for-a-limited-amount-of-time), I'd also like to run some code for a limited amount of time. However, I'd like to recover the value of some variables when the code is interrupted, which the answers in the question do not allow. A dummy example would be:

```
import time

limit = 10
counter = 0
start = time.time()
while(time.time() - start < limit):
    counter += 1
```

and this way I can recover `counter` after running the code for `limit` seconds. But I do not want to use this approach, because if the operation in the while loop takes a long time (e.g. > `limit`), it is still executed once - which I don't want.

How could I avoid this, but still get the value of some variables when the process is interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIGALRM and have a signal sent to your program each time. Because the argument is the stack frame, it's possible to read any variable from there.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import signal
import time

def alarm_handler (signo, frame):
    print ("SIGALRM: counter = %s" % frame.f_locals ["counter"])
    signal.alarm (2)

signal.signal (signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
signal.alarm (2)

counter = 0
while True:
    time.sleep (.5)
    counter += 1
```