# Logging output of file and process time out with python

Tags: python, timeout, subprocess, flush

I am going through a big list of files and running a command on all of them. I want to log the output and if the command takes more than 5 minutes for a file, I would like to stop the command and go to the next file.

I have two problems:

1. I want to record the file name to the output file and also record the output messages. I am using `Popen` to log the messages and using `communicate` so it gets logged, but all the filenames I am writing with `write()` don't get written till the whole task is done.
2. I am not sure how I can poll the process and quit it after 5 minutes and go to the next file.

Below is simplified code:

```
import os, fnmatch
import subprocess
import sys
f=open('filenames','w')

'Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below supplied root directory.'''

def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):        
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)


for filename in locate("*.dll"):
    f.write(filename)   
    #cmd defintion is changed for simplicity 
    cmd='cat %s' %filename
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=f)   
    p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: indent the code so its formatted please :) its chopping line breaks etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `f.flush()` after `f.write(filename)`.
2. See [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use, roughly:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

import subprocess
import sys
import threading
import os

class Execution(threading.Thread):
  comm = None
  proc = None
  returncode = None
  stdoutdata = None
  stderrdate = None

  def __init__(self, comm):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.comm = comm

  def run(self):
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(self.comm, bufsize=-1, stdin=None,  
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    self.proc.wait()
    (self.stdoutdata, self.stderrdata) = self.proc.communicate()
    self.returncode = self.proc.poll()

for curcommand in somecommandlist:
  ex = Execution(curcommand)
  starttime = time()
  ex.start()
  ex.join(some_timeout_in_seconds)

  wastimeout = False
  if (ex.isAlive()):
    wastimeout = True
    print("TIMEOUT OCCURRED @ %s" % (datetime.today(),))
    ex.proc.kill()

  ex.join()
  endtime = time()
  duration = endtime - starttime
  print("DURATION %s" % (duration,))

  exitcode = ex.returncode
  print("EXIT CODE: %s" % (exitcode,))
  print somepostprocessing(ex.stdoutdata,ex.stderrdata)
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Basically: start the process inside a separate thread. This is necessary because the `threading` module gives you timeout waiting, while the `subprocess` module does not. Wait until the timeout; check if the thread is still alive. If the thread is live, we cause it to terminate by killing the process (here, `subprocess` gives you a `kill()` construct, which `threading` does not) and waiting for the thread to end on its own accord.

Keep in mind that `communicate()` blocks and stores the *full* output from the child's stderr and stdout, so this may not work if the output is very large.

Comment: Very welcome. As a side note, I tested this under Windows (cygwin and plain python-for-windows 2.7) as well as Ubuntu.