# Is it possible to compile c code using python?

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I want to build a python program that get as input a path to .c file and then it compile its.

The program will output OK to the screen if the compilation is sucessful, and BAD otherwise.

I'm been trying to google it, but could not find anything. I've been also trying to run cmd within python with an argument of the compiling program but it didn't work.

To clarify -  I've already got a very specific compiler in my machine which I want to run. I dont want python to act as a compiler. Just get a code, run my compiler over it, and see what's the answer.

- It should work on Linux server with python 2.4.

Thanks

Comment: You might look in distutils but all that will be doing is providing a python layer to gcc or similar compiler, in the end python will no be doing the compiling and will have dependencies.

Comment: There is a nice Pycon talk [Using Python to debug C and C++ code (using gdb)](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-using-python-to-debug-c-and-c-code-using-gdb-4895525) may be it can help you.

Comment: If you want to run a compiler, you're just running a subprocess with Python.  In that case, this question is a total duplicate of every other question seeking to run a subprocess under Python.  Close it.  Here are all the related questions which all provide approximately the same answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+subprocess.  They all answer the "clarified" question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [subprocess with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, why not? Of course, you'd need GCC installed (or llvm) so you have something to compile with. You can just use os.system, or any of the other ways for calling an external program.

Of course, you're probably better off looking at something like [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), which already exists to solve this problem.

Plus, to answer the question actually asked, there's nothing that would prevent you from writing a compiler/assembler/linker in python, they're just programs like anything else. Performance probably wouldn't be very good though.

Comment: how does Scons help in this. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 10):

You can compile C code using only the standard library, and it will work on every platform and with every Python version (assuming you actually have a C compiler available). Check out the [`distutils.ccompiler`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.ccompiler) module which Python uses to compile C extension modules. A simple example:

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Compilation script:

```
# build.py
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compiler = new_compiler()
    compiler.compile(['main.c'])
    compiler.link_executable(['main.o'], 'main')
```

Everything else (include paths, library paths, custom flags or link args or macros) can be passed via various configuration options. Check out the above link to the module documentation for more info.

Comment: `<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives`

Answer (score 5):

The following steps should do the trick:

1. Get PLY.  Python Lex and Yacc.  http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/
2. Find a Yacc/Lex configuration for C.  http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html
3. Tweak PLY to use the C language rules you found.
4. Run.  You are "compiling" C code -- checking the syntax.

Comment: why so short instruction? start from "solder your own processor"

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you clearly, you just want to run compiler with some arguments from python?

In this case, you can just to use os.system. http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system

Or better way is module "subprocess". http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess