# How to import a C file into python

Tags: python, c

I made a GUI in Python and i just wanted to know how can i import a C file into python so every time a button is clicked on my GUI, different methods in the C program will be executed. I tried the 'Python' method of importing:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/Desktop/FTPclass.py')
import FTPclass
```

That worked for the python file i imported, but when I do the same for my c file, it complains saying my "testinc" module doesn't exist.

Thanks for everyone help in advance.
~Neamus

Comment: Do you want to call single functions from your c file or do you want to call a compiled program?

Comment: single functions. I would like every button to be unique.

Comment: "every time a button is clicked on my GUI, the C program will be executed": that sounds like you want to run the program as a separate executable (possibly passing additional input and capturing the output). Certainly if the GUI is just a layer on top of/wrapper around the C program. Perhaps the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module can help.

Comment: In addition to the question linked in the previous comment (which is about calling C functions from Python), check out [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/1782792). You may be able to compile our C code normally into a program and call that program from Python. What you definitely cannot do is executing uncompiled C code from Python (see [Is it possible to compile c code using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9420673) on that topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use c file according to docs you need to first compile C code and then use the compiled file in your code

here is the link.
Visit http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/python_c_extension.html