# Embed C in Python without a C compiler

Tags: python, c, cython

I have found this [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) about embedding C code into python, however this requires a C compiler to be installed.

Sadly the company that I am working does not allow for the installation of the C compiler, but we do have conda installed.

Is there a way to achieve this without the use of a compiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile c code using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420673/is-it-possible-to-compile-c-code-using-python)

Comment: You're going to have to get your C compiled *somehow*. It doesn't have to be on that machine - you could compile it on a different machine - but a compiler will have to be involved at some point.

Comment: @rochard4u: Nothing there is going to work without an external compiler installed. (Particularly, `distutils.ccompiler` is merely an interface to external compilers.)

Comment: Depending on the exact company policy: I think you can install compilers with Conda. It will be "limited" to that user and/or Conda environment, but it should work as normal.

Comment: @rochard4u that question is about running a compiler that's already installed, which doesn't seem possible here.  The answer showing how to do it without a compiler notes that it's a deprecated method.

Comment: Indeed, the linked post is a little irrelevent to the question. In any case, the answer to the question "Is there a way to achieve this without the use of a compiler?" should be no.

Comment: @user2357112 isn't compilation build specific? As in the compiler creates an excecutable specific for your machine.

Comment: @9769953 I did not know that that was possible. I will look into it. Thank you very much

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're really in a bind, WASM can help. You can bundle your own compiler, [Python](https://pythondev.readthedocs.io/wasm.html), whatever you want, into some WASM build that you then run within the WebAssembly environment.

Comment: @UlaşDemirtaş: It creates an executable specific for whatever platform you tell it to, which is much more general than just one specific machine. If every C program had to be compiled on the machine it was going to run on, you wouldn't have been able to install all the many, many C programs you're already using, including most of your OS and Python itself.