# python timeout using os.system

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, os.system

So, I know everyone is going to tell me to use the subprocess module, but I can't use that for  the project I am working on since Piping simply doesn't want to work with wxpython and py2exe on my system.

So, I've been using the os.system call.  I need to know how to wait for the process to end.
Currently, I have

```
os.system(cmd)
```

and my command may actually take a long time to execute, so it usually times out early.
How can I make my program to wait for os.system? I've tried waitpid and I guess that doesn't work for os.system.

I am developing for windows so I can't use fork and execvp unfortunately.  I have a lot of hands tied :(

Comment: os.system should not ever time out, and should not return until the process is complete. Perhaps your command is timing out?

Comment: related: [subprocess with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1191374/4279)

Answer (score 2):

you can correct your code:

```
os.system('cmd')
```

*extra explain about subprocess:*

```
import subprocess
ls_output = subprocess.check_output(['ls'])
```

*Running External Command*

To run an external command without interacting with it, such as one would do with `os.system()`, Use the `call()` function.

```
import subprocess

# Simple command
subprocess.call('ls -l', shell=True)
```

```
$ python replace_os_system.py
total 16
-rw-r--r--   1 root8085  root8085     0 Jul  1 13:27 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root8085  root8085  1316 Jul  1 13:27 replace_os_system.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root8085  root8085  1167 Jul  1 13:27 replace_os_system.py~
```

```
# run cmd

import subprocess
l = subprocess.call(['cmd'])
```

Extra example:
Make a system call three different ways:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
# Use a sequence of args
return_code = subprocess.call(["echo", "hello sequence"])

# Set shell=true so we can use a simple string for the command
return_code = subprocess.call("echo hello string", shell=True)

# subprocess.call() is equivalent to using subprocess.Popen() and wait()
proc = subprocess.Popen("echo hello popen", shell=True)
return_code = proc.wait() # wait for process to finish so we can get the return code
```

*Control stderr and stdout:*

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
# Put stderr and stdout into pipes
proc = subprocess.Popen("echo hello stdout; echo hello stderr >&2", \
        shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
return_code = proc.wait()
# Read from pipes
for line in proc.stdout:
    print("stdout: " + line.rstrip())
for line in proc.stderr:
    print("stderr: " + line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Has answered similar question in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094707/setting-timeout-when-using-os-system-function/65336126#65336126).

key point is:

use `subprocess.check_output` to instead `os.system`, for [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) support `timeout`:

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, encoding=None, errors=None, universal_newlines=None, **timeout**=None, text=None, **other_popen_kwargs)