# Python os.system timeout with strings

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm unable to execute the following line:

```
os.system("timeout 1s bash -c \"ffmpeg -i \""+path+\"+" | <some_<other_cmd>\"")
```

So the purpose of this command is to set a timeout for the whole command, i.e. pipelining some ffmpeg information from a path.

The problem is because bash -c "CMD" is expected, but the command also contains `" "`.

Is there another way of defining the `\"path\"`, because the path can contain spaces? Or another solution which can resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triple sinqle quotes can do the trick (so that you do not have to escape doublequotes):

```
os.system('''timeout 1s bash -c "ffmpeg -i "+path+"+" | cat''')
```

But in general.. Why not use `subprocess.call` that has saner syntax?

Comment: The problem occurs because there is a need to put quotes around the path because the path contains spaces, which your solution doesn't resolve. And I'm not familiar with python, I was just changing some old code for my needs. But I'll try to resolve the problem in a different manner so that I won't be needing to group the 2 commands for the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Has answered similar question in other posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094707/setting-timeout-when-using-os-system-function/65336126#65336126) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868500/python-timeout-using-os-system/65336158#65336158)

you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) related functions, which all support `timeout` parameter, to replace `os.system`

such as [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```py
ffmpegCmd = "ffmpeg -I %s | %s" % (path, someOtherCmd)
outputBytes = subprocess.check_output(ffmpegCmd, shell=True, timeout=1)
outputStr = outputBytes.decode("utf-8") # change utf-8 to your console encoding if necessary
```