# How to make a subprocess.call timeout using python 2.7.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, subprocess

This has probably been asked but I cannot find anything regarding a subprocess.call timeout when using python 2.7

Comment: have a look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout

Answer (score 16):

A simple way I've always done timeouts with 2.7 is utilizing `subprocess.poll()` alongside `time.sleep()` with a delay. Here's a very basic example:

```
import subprocess
import time

x = #some amount of seconds
delay = 1.0
timeout = int(x / delay)

args = #a string or array of arguments
task = subprocess.Popen(args)

#while the process is still executing and we haven't timed-out yet
while task.poll() is None and timeout > 0:
     #do other things too if necessary e.g. print, check resources, etc.
     time.sleep(delay)
     timeout -= delay
```

If you set `x = 600`, then your timeout would amount to 10 minutes. While `task.poll()` will query whether or not the process has terminated. `time.sleep(delay)` will sleep for 1 second in this case, and then decrement the timeout by 1 second. You can play around with that part to your heart's content, but the basic concept is the same throughout.

Hope this helps!

`subprocess.poll()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: This doesn't kill the process. You need to add os.killpg(os.getpgid(task.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

Comment: @AaronS I think `task.terminate()` does virtually the same.

Comment: if you don't change the process group of the new task, os.killpg(os.getpgid(task.pid) may kill all the processes with the same pg, not only the process executed by subprocess.Popen() and its children(!)

Answer (score 4):

You could install [`subprocess32` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/) [mentioned by @gps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698328/4279) -- the backport of the `subprocess` module from Python 3.2/3.3 for use on 2.x.  It works on Python 2.7 and it includes timeout support from Python 3.3.

[`subprocess.call()` is just `Popen().wait()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/03760b0a261dadf317f01ddfbcdf51e73fcfd49c/Lib/subprocess.py#L514-L522) and therefore to interrupt a long running process in `timeout` seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(*call_args)
time.sleep(timeout)
try:
    p.kill()
except OSError:
    pass # ignore
p.wait()
```

If the child process may end sooner then a portable solution is to [use `Timer()` as suggested in @sussudio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012262/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen
from threading import Timer

def kill(p):
    try:
        p.kill()
    except OSError:
        pass # ignore

p = Popen(*call_args)
t = Timer(timeout, kill, [p])
t.start()
p.wait()
t.cancel()
```

On Unix, you could [use `SIGALRM` as suggested in @Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191537/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
from subprocess import Popen

class Alarm(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Alarm

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)


p = Popen(*call_args)
signal.alarm(timeout)  # raise Alarm in 5 minutes
try:
    p.wait()
    signal.alarm(0)  # reset the alarm
except Alarm:
    p.kill()
    p.wait()
```

To avoid using threads and signals here, `subprocess` module on Python 3 uses a [busy loop with `waitpid(WNOHANG)` calls on Unix](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7b2ba5601ae02ec046853a5e468160d443cf24f7/Lib/subprocess.py#L1607-L1653) and [`winapi.WaitForSingleObject()` on Windows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7b2ba5601ae02ec046853a5e468160d443cf24f7/Lib/subprocess.py#L1260-L1275).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use **"easyprocess"**:

https://github.com/ponty/EasyProcess

It has many features that you need like **"timeout"**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess32](https://pypi.org/project/subprocess32/) [mentioned by @gps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698328/4279), which is backport of the subprocess standard library module from Python 3.2 - 3.5 for use on Python 2.

Firstly, install the subprocess32 module:

```
pip install subprocess32
```

Here's a code snippet:

```
>>> import subprocess32
>>> print subprocess32.check_output(["python", "--version"])
Python 2.7.12

>>> subprocess32.check_output(["sleep", "infinity"], timeout=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 340, in check_output
    raise TimeoutExpired(process.args, timeout, output=output)
subprocess32.TimeoutExpired: Command '['sleep', 'infinity']' timed out after 3 seconds
```

Notice, default `timeout=None`, which means never timeout.

Answer (score -5):

In python 3.3 *timeout* argument was added.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: Thanks for your response.I know that we are using python 2.7.6