# Using Python's subprocess module, is there a way to skip an execution when the call gets stuck?

Tags: python, subprocess

As part of a larger program, I am using

a `subprocess.call('some external program', shell=True)`

(It is an old C program and I only have the compiled version sitting on a network server, so I can't just grab the C source code and interface it with Python)

to temporarily generate some data, which I read into Python again.
The problem is that the external program called via subprocess sometimes gets stuck on certain input files.
Is there a way to skip the `subprocess.call()`, e.g., if the shell doesn't respond after some arbitrary time limit?

```
E.g., 

# for data in directory:
    # do sth.
    subprocess.call('call prog.', shell=True) # skip if takes longer than 5 min
    # analyze data
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [subprocess with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Python 3.3 you can set the [timeout argument](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) in seconds:

```
try:
    return_code = subprocess.call('call prog.', shell=True, timeout=10)
except TimeoutExpired:
    # handle timeout exception here which gets throw after
    # 10 seconds in this example
```