# How do I make python to wait for a return value limited time?

Tags: python

I'm calling a method which run time is undefiniable.
I want to wait for it some second (for example 2 sec) and after then I want to step my program next.

Comment: use `time.sleep(s)` from `time` module. `import time; time.sleep(2)`

Comment: What's the method? Maybe `time.sleep` is a valid solution, but it could cause race conditions.

Comment: You need to do a basic Google search before asking a question: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: This is actually a much more complicated question than everyone is treating it.  What you want to do is use `multiprocessing` or `threading` to start a child thread that executes the method.  You then want the parent to  kill the child if it hasn't returned a value after the allotted time.  This is not easy stuff.  Why don't you do some reading on those two modules and come back when you have more concrete questions.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a more suitable answer to the question: [break the function after certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027122/break-the-function-after-certain-time)

P.S: Could not post it as a comment due to insufficient reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the sleep function in the time module.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep/%22time.sleep%22)