# Break the function after certain time. (C++)

Tags: c++, exception, subprocess, signals

My Question resonated exactly with following question.

[break the function after certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027122/break-the-function-after-certain-time)

However, the above question revolves around Python implementation. I am trying to implement the same thing in C++. Here is the code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdexcept>

void handle_alarm( int sig ) {
    printf("%d",sig); 
    throw std::invalid_argument("none");
}

int main() {

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        signal( SIGALRM, handle_alarm ); 
        printf("Doing normal work %d \n",i);
        alarm(120);

        try {
            for (;;){}    // It will be replaced by a function which can take very long time to evaluate.
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument& e ) {
        continue; 
        } 
    }   
}
```

> Problem statement

: With each iteration of the loop, a function XYZ, which can take a long time in evaluation, will be called (replaced by a infinite for loop in above code). My objective is to termination the execution of the function, if it takes more than 2 min, and continue to the next iteration.

However, this give me the error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'`. I had also tried to use a custom exception class, but the error persist.

I am unable to figure out whats wrong with this specific implementation, or whether there exist another better approach for it? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Throwing in a signal handler is bad. You should not do very advanced things in a signal handler, ultimately it should just set a flag (preferably an atomic flag) that you then check.

Comment: What you're looking for is "Coroutines".. Not sure if C++ has them, but in C# and Unity3D, you can do it.

Comment: @Brandon "Coroutines" seems to have a chance. However, can you please provide any reference, which discuss them in this context.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with the `async` [launch policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch).

Then you can use [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) of the returned [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) to wait only a specific time for a result.

If you don't get a result within the time-frame, then save the future (it can't be [destructed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) until it has a result!) but just ignore it and its possible result.

This will not really "break" the function, it will still continue until it is finished. But it is a way to continue your program anyway.

---

Another possible solution is to use [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and in it continually check for timeouts, or for some ([atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)) flag to know if it should continue or not.

Comment: wait_for seems a nice option, but it is not suitable for my task. I have a 1000's of iteration and if each one isn't terminated, it will result in a high latency.