# Is there a way to do parrallelization in an Airflow task?

Tags: python, airflow

My problem: I am trying to retrieve data from Google Ads. Sometimes the API call hangs indefinitely.

My idea: Create a separate process that monitors if the process doing the API call has returned data or has reached the timeout limit.

What I have tried:

- I looked into doing Threading. This doesn't work because I cannot terminate a thread like I can a process. I have read that I can use flags to make it stop itself but that won't work because the API call hangs and there is no further python code executed.
- I looked into multiprocessing. This works fine in isolation but you cannot spawn a new process from an Airflow task.
- I looked into using signals, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027122/break-the-function-after-certain-time). This also works well in isolation but the alarm signal is sent to the main process which is Airflow and not the process doing my task and my error catching only happens in my own task.
- I tried looking into how I can launch a task a new Python interpreter instance but couldn't find how. There is a way to make all tasks start with a new Python interpreter instance apparently, by using the [execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#execute-tasks-new-python-interpreter) setting in the airflow.cfg file but when I switch that to true my task gets stuck at scheduling and never proceeds to start running.
- I tried using the PythonVirtualenvOperator operator but after installing virtualenv by the method stated in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator), Airflow says it can't find the package. But it's there because if I activate the virtual environment of Airflow itself, I can import it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you add a timeout to your retrieve call in the first place?  That's always a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I also tried to do the same, multiprocessing, multithreading, but then I found out that Airflow applies parallelization by design. create multiple tasks to do the same job and you've parallelized :-)

You don't have to write all the tasks separately but you can just loop through a list and create multiple jobs like that.

Hope it helps