# What are the recommended ways to deal with multiprocessing and sleep?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

So, I've been playing with Python's `multiprocessing` module for a few days now, and there's something that I can't understand. Maybe someone can give me a bit of help.

I'm trying to run two methods from the same class in parallel, but apparently there's something that I'm missing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def meth1(self):
        print(1)
        time.sleep(10)

    def meth2(self):
        print(2)
        time.sleep(5 * 60)


def main():
    while True:
        s = SomeClass()

        p1 = Process(target=s.meth1)  # I want this to run from 10 to 10 seconds
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target=s.meth2)  # I want this to run from 5 to 5 minutes
                                      # while the first one still does its own
                                      # job from 10s to 10s
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I would expect to happen is:

- the first method should print `1`;
- then the second one should print `2` (without waiting 10s - which does happen and seems to work as expected);
- then I should see only 1s for the next 4 minutes and 50s (this isn't happening and the program just *waits* for that time to pass.

What am I missing? Why does the second step work as expected, but the 3rd one doesn't? How can I make it work?

Comment: @wp78de feel free to edit the title if you can think of a better one ^^

Comment: `meth1` only prints `1` once. Why would you expect it to keep doing that?

Comment: @user2357112 because of the `while True`? Should print `1` every 10 seconds :)

Comment: Were you expecting the `while` loop to run `meth1` every 10 seconds? That loop waits for both processes to finish. It has to wait for `meth2` to finish before running another `meth1`.

Comment: Then why does the second method not wait for the first 10 seconds to finish in order to print `2`?

Comment: The loop doesn't wait for p1 to finish until after it's already started p2. It waits for both processes to finish before launching a new batch of two processes.

Comment: So to answer your question: I wasn't expecting the `while` loop to run `meth1` every 10 seconds but instead, I was expecting `meth1` to print `1` and `meth2` to print `2` at the same time (barely), then while `meth2` is sleeping, I was expecting for `meth1` to still do its job and print `1` from 10 to 10 seconds. I thought that's the use of `multiprocessing`. what did I do wrong?

Comment: While `meth2` is sleeping, your `main` is waiting at `p2.join()` and `meth1` cannot run again until the `while` loop starts again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to really know what you want, but this code below does what you describe, but has no convenient way of exiting:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def meth1(self):
        while True:
            print(1)
            time.sleep(10)


    def meth2(self):
        while True:
            print(2)
            time.sleep(5 * 60)


def main():
    s = SomeClass()

    p1 = Process(target=s.meth1)  # I want this to run from 10 to 10 seconds
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=s.meth2)  # I want this to run from 5 to 5 minutes while the first one still does its own job from 10s to 10s
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have moved the `while` into each of the methods of `SomeClass`

This code will never exit, hanging at `p1.join()`

Answer (score 1):

Think of processes as friends / clones of yours that you can call on the phone, have come in and do something, and then when they are all done they go home, leaving you a note.

The lines:

```
p1 = Process(target=s.meth1)
p1.start()
```

call one clone up and have him run `s.meth1`.  He comes over and prints 1 on your screen, waits 10 seconds, then leaves you a note: "all done, no exceptions occurred, I've gone home".

Meanwhile (while your first clone is coming over), the lines:

```
p2 = Process(target=s.meth2)
p2.start()
```

call up another clone and have him run `s.meth2`.  He comes over, prints 2 on your screen, waits around for 5 minutes, then leaves you a note: "all done, no exceptions occurred, I've gone home".

While clones #1 and #2 are doing their work, the line:

```
p1.join()
```

waits for clone #1 to leave you his note.  That happens after 10 seconds.  You then go on to:

```
p2.join()
```

which waits for clone #2 to leave you his note.  That happens after another 4 minutes and 50 seconds.  Then you go back around to your `while True` and start everything over again.

If you want *not* to wait for clone #2 to finish and leave you his note, don't call `p2.join()` yet.  Eventually, though, you *should* call `p2.join()` to make sure that everything went well and that he went home successfully, and isn't lying dead in your living room in a pool of blood, shot by some exception. :-)

Comment: Nice ELI5 answer. Though...removing `p2.join()` won't have the desired result either. Removing it will still print `1\n2\n1\n2...` which is not what I want. I'd expect `1\n2\n1\n1\n1\n1\n...2 (after 4 mins and x seconds)... and so on`

Comment: "Don't call it *yet*" doesn't mean "don't call it".  Moreover, if p2 is still running, you obviously don't want to start it again either.  What you might consider doing is waiting for *either one* to finish. See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064238/1256452) to a related question.