# How to call a system command with specified time limit in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm creating a Python application that calls a few system commands. However, I want it to terminate those commands if they take too much time (say, 10s). I tried to do this on my own, using some subprocesses - without much success. After searching on stackoverflow, I found the following question:
[Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

It has an answer, that *almost* works for me - the problem is, that when the process is "terminated", it actually *isn't* - in fact, the process remains running in the background even after my script finishes. Of course this is not a desirable effect, but I can't find a workaround. Is there a preffered solution to this problem?

Code from mentioned answer (the bad one) for reference:

```
import subprocess, threading

class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self, timeout):
        def target():
            print 'Thread started'
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True)
            self.process.communicate()
            print 'Thread finished'

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print 'Terminating process'
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()
        print self.process.returncode

command = Command("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'")
command.run(timeout=3)
command.run(timeout=1)
```

Comment: If you can use Python ≥3.3, that has a *timeout* argument for `Popen.wait()`. This will raise a *TimeoutExpired* exception if the child doesn't finish within the timeout period. You can then call `Popen.kill()` to forcibly terminate the child process.

Comment: Thanks, but I use 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer here:

[How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

just add `preexec_fn=os.setsid` to the `Popen` command

Terminate using:

```
os.killpg(self.process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Instead of:

```
self.process.terminate()
```

Don't forget to `import os,signal`

so you will get:

```
import subprocess, threading
import os,signal
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self, timeout):
        def target():
            print 'Thread started'
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
            self.process.communicate()
            print 'Thread finished'

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print 'Terminating process'
            os.killpg(self.process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            thread.join()
        print self.process.returncode

command = Command("echo 'Process started'; sleep 2; echo 'Process finished'")
command.run(timeout=3)
command.run(timeout=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Could you explain why the previous version (with terminate()) didn't work?

Comment: if it is a dup, flag it as a dup.