# How to timeout when I use subprocess

Tags: python, process

I use sub.Popen in Python2.7

But, Python3 has timeout but, Python2.7 can't it.

it is my snippet.

```
proc = sub.Popen(['some command', 'some params'], stdout=sub.PIPE)    

try:
    for row in proc.stdout:
        print row.rstrip()   # process here
        result = str(row.rstrip())
        count += 1
        if count > 10:
            break
except:
    print 'tcpdump error'
    proc.terminate()
```

How to set timeout to it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this blog post](http://www.ostricher.com/2015/01/python-subprocess-with-timeout/) code with a couple of changes you can use  threading.Thread:

```
from threading import Thread
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


def proc_timeout(secs, *args):
    proc = Popen(args, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    proc_thread = Thread(target=proc.wait)
    proc_thread.start()
    proc_thread.join(secs)
    if proc_thread.is_alive():
        try:
            proc.kill()
        except OSError:
            return proc.returncode
        print('Process #{} killed after {} seconds'.format(proc.pid, secs))
    return proc
```

You should only catch specific exceptions in your try/except, don't try to catch them all.

Comment: @shinriyo, no worries, not overly tested the code but should do what you want. It will raise a SubprocessTimeoutError if the command does not return within secs

Comment: Hey,
Managed to use this, but I can't find a way to record STDOUT with this.
``proc = Popen(args, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)``
Won't let you read from stdout. It makes me get: an error reading from closed file. Any way around that?

Comment: How are you running it, I edited the answer removing the raise as you probably always want the output before the timeout

Comment: I was actually using the raise. Looks like it works. Great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux (or possibly other unix derivatives) you could use the [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command. For example:

```
subprocess.Popen(['timeout', '5', 'sleep', '20']).wait()
```

will timeout after 5 seconds. `proc.communicate()` should also work with this method.

Other alternatives can be found in this related question: [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/subprocess-with-timeout)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I didn't know "timeout" the linux command.