# How to implement a subprocess timeout?

Tags: python, subprocess

I wan to implement a timeout on the child spawned by a subprocess call.

So as a test:

```
#!/home/depot/.conda/envs/python3/bin/python
import subprocess                                                     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.call('./sleep.py', timeout=1)
```

The `sleep.py` file being run:

```
#!/home/depot/.conda/envs/python36/bin/python
from time import sleep

if __name__ =="__main__":
     for j in range(3):
         print(j)
         sleep(1)
```

Now clearly this doesn't implement any timeout.

I was a bit surprised as the doc seems to suggest that timeout is indeed an option in:
[Using the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

However other answers on SO seems to disregard that functionality and advocate for the creation of a custom made timer:
[Subprocess timeout does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355136/subprocess-timeout-does-not-work)
[Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout)

How is it possible to implement a timeout with the builtin `timeout` argument?

Comment: Works as expected for me. After 1 second I get a `subprocess.TimeoutExpired` exception and sleep.py is killed. What happens for you? What version of python are you using? (I have tested on 3.4 and 3.5 - both work). What OS are you using?

Comment: @Gavin In my case the script sleep.py just continue until the end without stopping after the timeout. I am on Linux, using python 3.6 (I also tried with 3.4 with similar results). I added the shebang at the start of the script. This is the actual way I am calling them - maybe that does make a difference?

Comment: Hm are the shebangs supposed to be different? I tend to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` so that it grabs the first python on the path (and let virtualenv manage it), so perhaps something is happening with the multiple environment setup.