# why check_output can work without setting 'shell=True'

Tags: python-3.x

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698328/391104

The above post said that `shell=True` should not be be used within `check_output`. However, I cannot even make it work without using the `shell=True`.

What is the issue?

Python 3.5.1

```
>>> from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output
>>> check_output('ls -l', stderr=STDOUT, timeout=10)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line
>   629, in check_output
>       **kwargs).stdout   File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line
>   696, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line
>   950, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line
>   1544, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls -l'

However,

```
>>> check_output('ls -l', stderr=STDOUT, timeout=10, shell=True)
```

works as expected

== Update for AnilRedshift ==

```
# work w/o problems
try:
    subprocess.check_output("rsync -ae 'ssh -q' /tmp/hello*.txt machine:/tmp", timeout=20, shell=True)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print(e)

# fail
try:
    args = shlex.split("rsync -ae 'ssh -q' /tmp/hello*.txt machine:/tmp")
    subprocess.check_output(args, timeout=20)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print(e)

CalledProcessError: Command '['rsync', '-ae', 'ssh -q', '/tmp/hello*.txt', 'machine:/tmp']' returned non-zero exit status 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `shell=True`, the first thing that happens is that your command is parsed via shell semantics.

In this case, `ls -l` becomes `['ls', '-l']`.

So, if you want to do this yourself, without the shell, you need to split your command into arg chunks.

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output
check_output(['ls', '-l'], stderr=STDOUT, timeout=10)
```

If you have a more complicated command, you can use [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) as a helper:

```
import shlex
args = shlex.split("ls -l")
check_output(args, stderr=STDOUT, timeout=10)
```

Comment: Please see my comment in OP.

Comment: @q0987: Your updated question is a separate issue. `*` has no meaning to `ls`. If you go into a terminal and type `ls *.txt`, your **shell** first parses the command, and expands `'*.txt'` to every .txt in the current directory, and that is passed to ls. As you can see, this glob-expanding is a feature of the shell, and thus why you would need `shell=True` for that to work.