# Python: How to kill command after timeout

Tags: python

I am using python command

```
import commands
tmp = "my command" #any command like ls
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(tmp)
```

It works perfectly. Now i have few commands which may take more than 5 seconds or stuck forever. I want to kill such commands after 5 second. 
Any pointers.

Comment: You can use a subprocess module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module (`commands` is deprecated).

```py
import shlex, subprocess, time
command = "command"
args = shlex.split(command)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)

start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if p.poll() is not None:
        break

if p.returncode is not None:
    p.kill()
```

Comment: how do i get status and output?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the easiest solution:

```
from easyprocess import EasyProcess
tmp = "my command" #any command like ls
s = EasyProcess(tmp).call(timeout=5)
print "return_code: ",s.return_code
print "output: ", s.stdout
```