# Python how to continue for loop after 5 second

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import commands
    f = open("test.txt","r").readlines()    
    for l in f:
            x = l.strip()
            url = ("https://"+x+"/test")
            c = commands.getoutput("curl -I "+url)
            print (c)
```

When the code is executed, the code takes a long time in this line          [c = commands.getoutput("curl -I "+url)], I want to set a time for example 5 seconds. If it is longer than 5 seconds, move to the next line in the9 for loop)

Comment: you could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout

Comment: This is not easy. It will probably require a subprocess

Comment: If you're committed to using curl, this may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout/94612

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `requests` instead curl for handling response timeouts:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts.
Something like this:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

import commands

f = open("test.txt","r").readlines()    
for l in f:
    x = l.strip()
    url = ("https://"+x+"/test")
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    except Timeout:
        # do something
        continue
```