# Python subprocess kill child process then parent then restart again

Tags: python, subprocess

Sorry i am new in python subprocess world and I am lost a bit .
We have python script `run.py` and from `run.py` we are calling another python file named `start_process.py` using `subprocess` and then in `start_process.py` we are starting processes using again `subprocess`

Basically sudo code goes like

`run.py` :

```
def call_process_script():
    cmd = "python start_process.py"
    sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

while True:  
    call_process_script()
```

`start_process.py`:

```
cmd = "java somejava process"
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(
                    cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                )
stdoutdata, stderrdata = sub_proc.communicate()
```

Now I want to restart the `java process` after sometime . But I am not able to handle it or control from `run.py` or `start_process.py`.

I tried to force stop as mentioned and start but no luck  [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout)

Comment: No Actually. I cant change the script you mentioned . And still trying looking at this https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/05/17/python-101-how-to-timeout-a-subprocess/

Comment: Also one observation is force stopping the `python start_process.py` not stopping the `java process` invoked by it