# Rebooting a remote ubuntu server via Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Can someone let me know how can I reboot a remote server via Python ?

I tried the below command:-

```
os.system('sudo ssh -q -i /home/support/.ssh/id_rsa_vnera_cluster_keypair -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null support@a.b.c.d "sudo -S su ubuntu -c 'sudo reboot --force'"')
```

But my code was stuck in the above command waiting for the response as the `reboot` command does not return anything.

- OS - Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ideas for you:

1. Try using `nohup` in the command string you send the remote server.
2. Rather than use `os.system` (which is synchronous) use `subprocess.Popen()` (which may be used synchronously or asychronously) as follows:

> ```
> import subprocess as sp
>
> p = sp.Popen(['sudo', 'ssh', '-q' ...])  # complete the list with the rest of your remote command
>
> p.wait()    # if you want to wait.  Can include a timeout in wait().
> ```

Comment: `nohup` also has the same problem. It is stuck,

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` should work then as it is asynchronous (ie returns immediately).  If the remote machine subsequently reboots, then that would solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012262/785523 - I have seen this answer. How can I know if the process ended normally or was timed out ?

Comment: `status = p.poll()` will return immediately.  If `status is None` then process still running.  If process has completed, the `status` will be the exit code, 0 if completed OK.