# How to successfully terminate child process created via subporcess run

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables

We are running a java process, we want to stop execution after timeout, on timeout we get exception for timeout but java process is still running in background since we are using shell=True

Here is similar example

`subprocess.run("ping 8.8.8.8",timeout=1, shell=True,)`

however after timeout child process is still running

`subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'ping 8.8.8.8' timed out after 0.9998808979980822 seconds 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=10.7 ms 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=10.1 ms`

Some post suggested to drop `shell=True`, this does work for simple case, however for our java program we want to specify JAVA_OPTS but without shell we cannot set environment variables.

Is there a way to use `subprocess.run` which would kill child process post timeout expires

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout)

Comment: For environment variables: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html `env`

Comment: Thanks @Dschoni these do solve some of issue but not these once exactly

Comment: You do have several issues that are not neccesarily connected. You could open a subprocess with a timeout as in my first comment. You could drop `shell=True` when piping environment variables to the subprocess in the first place. You could kill the subprocess manually after some timeout in the main thread.... etc. pp.