# Code for waiting my previous condition for 2 minutes if not work , then raise an error message using python

Tags: python

I hope that everyone is okay :

i just would like to write a code in python for checking my server command (df -h ) , if this command will not give result for 2 minutes , an error message will write to me , otherwise will pass , any idea how can implement this using python .

Comment: This has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the wait method for a subprocess object?
like this example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#call sleep with arg = 5 seconds
l = Popen(['sleep','5'])

#wait for 4 seconds
l.wait(4)
```

If you run this, you will have an error after 4 seconds, but if you change the argument for the wait function for 6 for example, it wont return any error.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that the process will continue. If you want to stop it, i will need to call l.kill() method.