# stdout.readline() statement of subprocess is stuck if there is no data in stdout.How to break the loop?

Tags: python, node.js, subprocess, stdout

I am trying to `readline` from `stdout` of `subprocess`. Sometimes device "123" doesn't respond and won't provide and data in `stdout`. In that case line `out = proc.stdout.readline()` is getting stuck forever. How to come out of loop if there is no response from device.

I am trying to read `stdout` of a subprocess. below is the code.

```py
cmd = ["node", "transformerMonitor.js", "-h", "sample.com", "-s", "123"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
time_out = 120
start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < time_out:
    out = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(out)
```

if device doesn't respond. `out = proc.stdout.readline()` is stuck forever. How to break the loop if there is no response.

Comment: just to know `proc.wait` and `proc.communicate` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) have a `timeout` parameter and processes may receive signals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Once the subprocess finishes/fails and there are no more responses from the device, `out` will be an empty string. We can break out of the loop using this fact.

**Code:**

```py
import subprocess
import time

cmd = ["node", "transformerMonitor.js", "-h", "sample.com", "-s", "123"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
time_out = 120
start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < time_out:
    out = proc.stdout.readline()
    # If empty string output (No Response from Device), break out of loop.
    if not out:
        break
print('Code Finished')
```

**Output:**

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sapta\Documents\testing\transformerMonitor.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
Code Finished
```

Comment: Since there are no new lines/data , line 'out = proc.stdout.readline()' will stuck forever code wont go to next line.